# 2.82a wireframe disappears (glitch?)

Tags: wireframe

This has happened to me only in 2.82a:

while im in wireframe mode,and i do "Toggle Overlay",part of the wireframe disappears,as you can see in the pictures

Is it a glitch,or am i missing some specific setting ? Never happened with previous builds

[image: with overlay ON]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a glitch. If you disable the overlay you are basically disabling everything under it including bringing down the value of the wireframe under overlays.

[image]

if the value of the wireframe is less than 1, then it all disappears

[image]

you can still manually disable grid, floor, Axes, etc under overlays

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Thing is,if i do the very same thing on 2.8, 2.81 this won' t happen.Disabling the overlay on previous builds just doesnt affect the wireframe,I just also tried to move that Wireframe slide inside "Viewport Overlays",the one you underlined,and while Toggle Overlays is on,sliding it doesnt even have effect on 2.82,while on previous builds it does and actually changes the "amount" of wireframe shown.Can you reproduce the problem or its just me ?